# redirect all URLs to domain root with htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to get all requests including get variables to redirect to another domain with an htaccess rewrite,

I am trying to redirect all URLs from from my old blog to http://www.passiveincomeidea.com domain root but any URLs with a variable are still passing the variable to the new domain, like this one for example http://mika.lepisto.com/?p=2223

Here is what I have currently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.passiveincomeidea.com/ [L,R=301]
```

How can I get the rewrite to strip all the variables during the redirect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append a question mark at the end of redirected URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.passiveincomeidea.com/? [L,R=301]
```

For documentation, search for "Modifying the Query String" in the [`mod_rewrite` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).